# Can't eval break statement

Tags: javascript, eval

Why is this piece of code :

```
    var myBreak = 'break;';
    for(var i=0; i < 5; i++) {
        console.log('i is : ' + i);
        eval(myBreak);
    }
    console.log('done !');
```

triggering the :

```
unlabelled break must be inside loop or switch
```

error message in Firebug in place of returning `done !` in the console ?

Is it not possible to `eval()` break statements ?

Thank you in advance !

EDIT :

I'm getting confused now. ^^

- Why does it fail ?
- Is Jack Wanders right then with eval having it's
  own 'execution context' ?
- If yes, why isn't his example working ?

Comment: why are you using `eval` anyways?

Comment: I was only testing some "weird" cases of JavaScript and then tried this example just by curiosity.

Comment: My guess is that because `eval` code has its own execution context, it's not aware of the `for` loop it's within.

Comment: @jackwanders your guess is correct :)

Comment: @jackwanders hum, I don't really understand what it means but thank you anyway for your quick answer !

Comment: I actually think that "am not i am"'s answer was correct. See, the string must be at least syntactically correct, and a `break` statement alone is a syntax error. This has nothing to do with the execution context.

Comment: @Do you know then why Jack Wanders code snippet fails ? thank you !

Comment: I can only guess here: It might be that execution contexts are considered as functions and the label lookup cannot cross function boundaries. See http://es5.github.com/#x12.8.

Comment: Think of it as a JS file linked inside a JS file or a script tag inside a script tag. Neither of which  gets looked at until the outer code executes. The outer code can't know how it's going to interact with the inner code until it's parsed and evaluated and vice versa so stuff that wouldn't work independently fails round 1 of error-checking at the earliest parsing/interpreting phase for that new JS interpreter instance.

Comment: **same problem for `return`**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

eval parses/evaluates code in a new instance of the JavaScript interpreter. The code eventually executes in context with the original interpreter's code but the code has to be able to execute without that external context because the new instance is blind to it.

So `alert(eval(this.constructor.name))` will give you the proper object context name (window in global).

But these will fail because the instances don't 'see' each other's code until it's been evaluated by the separate interpreters and at this phase one piece fails without the other:

- `try{}eval('catch(){}');`
- `for(;;){ eval('break;'); }`
- `myLoop: eval('for(;;){ break myLoop; }');`

Short version: Code will work as expected but anything in an eval would have to be something you could fire in any other context by itself.

So basically, preliminary parsing/error-checking is done before values and scope and object context are considered. Once that's all done the code can act in concert and be checked for things like whether you're calling a var that hasn't been defined yet. Before that, the new interpreter only sees what's in the eval when it checks for errors. In the case of a that break, what it doesn't see is a loop or a switch surrounding it.

Loop labels are considered during this early parsing/evaluation phase whereas stuff like var existence and function labels appear to be checked later.

Answer (score 2):

`eval` code executes in its own execution context; basically, this means that when the `break;` executes, it does not know that it's being executed inside a `for` loop.

If you label the `break`, it should work:

```
var myBreak = 'break myLoop;';

myLoop:
  for(var i=0; i < 5; i++) {
    console.log('i is : ' + i);
    eval(myBreak);
  }

console.log('done !');
```

Comment: Oh ok. Now I understand ! Thank you very much for the explanation ! I will accept then answer in 6min.

Comment: SyntaxError: Label 'myLoop' is not defined

Comment: @Nile yeah, not sure why that's happening; I get the error too now that I test it. I'm following MDN here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label

Comment: @Nile I get the same error. Is it possible that it is again a problem with the "execution context" where the break doesn't know myLoop or something like this ?

Comment: @AwakeZoldiek that would be my guess. If you replace the eval statement with an explicit `break myLoop;`, it works fine. The only conclusion is that even if you label the loop, you can not reference it from the context of the `eval`

Comment: @jackwanders, However `break` throws Illegal-Break error, which isn't thrown by `break label`. Why?