# why does eval() not work here?

Tags: javascript

## First of all

I know `eval()` is evil, but this is a theoritical question.

Suppose I have a loop:

```
function loop() {
    for(var i = 0 ;i <= 10; i++) {
        $('ul').append('RUN :' + i + '<br>');
            eval('break;');
    }
}
```

while just putting `break;` in the place of `eval()` it works, but when same is done using `eval('break;')`, it results in a error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal break statement"

Also, i know to break the loop, I can use:

```
return false;
```

But why this behavior at first place?

Comment: [Some](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6684046/javascript-eval-method) possible [duplicates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11961963/cant-eval-break-statement).

Comment: It's not the loop, just doing `eval('break;')` gets you the same error, as break shouldn't be eval'ed

Comment: @adeneo, my question is why?

Comment: Because it's a statement, and what good would it do to eval a statement and return the result, the `break` statement has no context in `eval()`, so it's an error, it's like just randomly typing `break` somewhere.

Comment: Because you're just evaling a `break` in the middle of nowhere, like if you just typed `break` in the console.

Comment: Okay. So guys, please post it as answer so i can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

eval-ed code's context is in the same namespace as that of the caller, so variables, functions etc. are available for the code in eval, but not the program structure itself.

Comment: what do you mean by "not the program structure"

Comment: such as the "break" statement or any "for", "while", curly brace and so on

Comment: From now .. i'll keep in mind .. is .. Eval just work as a different console..only!! and it is sooooo dangerous.. As i got 2 down-votes for it.. :)